# Exit status of "git log --all --grep"

Tags: git

I want to search over several git repos, if there is a given commit message.

```
git log --all --grep='magic-message' > /dev/null; echo $?
```

But it seems that the exit status is always 0 in both cases (match or no match).

How to search the commit messages including a matching exit status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `git log` returns 0 to indicate that nothing broke (thereby suppressing the code from internal call to`grep`), `grep` itself has a return code that is more useful. You can make the call to `grep` manually using a pipeline:

```
git log --all | grep -q 'magic-message'
```

`-q` suppress all the output, just like your redirect does. It is the standard flag to use `grep` in a test, as you seem to want to do.